# Question about Schwartz-Zippel lemma

Tags: probability, polynomials

I am confused about the following:
The well know Schwartz-Zippel lemma states the following, let $p$ be degree $d$ polynomial in any field, $F$, (e.g $\;\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{Q}$,$\mathbb{F}_q$). And let $S\subset F$ a finite subset then:
$$
P
\left(p(x)=0,x\stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow} S\vert p\neq 0\right)\leq \frac{d}{\vert S\vert}
$$

Consider the following example: $F=\mathbb{R}, S=\{0,1,2\}, p=ax+b$. And suppose the random point drawn from $S$ is $1$. Then, the above equation is:
$$
P(a+b=0\vert \exists x: a\cdot x+b\neq 0)\leq \frac{1}{3}
$$

However, I thought Schwartz-Zippel bounds was tight, when clearly:
$
P(a+b=0\vert \exists x: a\cdot x+b\neq 0)=0.
$

Which means Schwartz-Zippel is not sharp in this case (meaning it's not sharp when considered for all polynomials of degree 1, not for one particular polynomial). What am I missing? Thanks!

P.S: The notation $x\stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow} S$ means $x$ sampled uniformly from $S$.

Comment: I don't get where the problem is, since $0 \le 1/3$ is true. If $a=1$ and $b=-1$, then the probability in your example is exactly $1/3$

Comment: @Crostul. It's not a contradiction per se. It's just, the bound is supposed to be sharp. However here it is not. I'll edit the post for clarity.

Comment: @Crostul. Ah, sorry my bad. You're right, stupid question. Thanks!